# ZF2 forward plugin dispatches wrong View

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a weird problem. I am trying to widgetize my website by creating a ViewHelper which contains and this piece of code but for some reason it doesn't work as expected:

```
//....
$forward  = $serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('Forward');    
$view = $forward->dispatch('Application\Controller\Widgets', array('action' => 'notexistingaction'));
$view1 = $forward->dispatch('Application\Controller\Widgets', array('action' => 'existingaction'));

    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($view);
    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($view1);

//....
```

The result is

```
    object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)#713 (7) {
  ["captureTo":protected] => string(7) "content"
  ["children":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["options":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["template":protected] => string(9) "error/404"
  ["terminate":protected] => bool(false)
  ["variables":protected] => array(4) {
    ["content"] => string(14) "Page not found"
    ["message"] => string(15) "Page not found."
    ["reason"] => string(32) "error-controller-cannot-dispatch"
    ["display_exceptions"] => bool(true)
  }
  ["append":protected] => bool(false)
}

object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)#716 (7) {
  ["captureTo":protected] => string(7) "content"
  ["children":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["options":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["template":protected] => string(9) "error/404"
  ["terminate":protected] => bool(false)
  ["variables":protected] => object(Zend\View\Variables)#717 (2) {
    ["strictVars":protected] => bool(false)
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private] => array(3) {
      ["message"] => string(15) "Page not found."
      ["reason"] => string(32) "error-controller-cannot-dispatch"
      ["display_exceptions"] => bool(true)
    }
  }
  ["append":protected] => bool(false)
}
```

Question WHY ??
Technically there should be one with error and other one to be displayed its content .. but for some reason both appears as 404

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your route config it is hard to say exactly whats wrong. But from the dumps looks like it cant dispatch your forward and looking at the actions you are forwarding you have added "action" at the end. so the name of the action would be "existingactionAction"

Comment: Those are just dummy names the actual action names are obviously different .. the thing is when first forward dispatches a non existing action ( returning a 404 )  then all other dispatched actions will return 404 as well ( no matter if action exist or not ) which is not quite right from my perspective